# Dynamic worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a dynamic name that can help pull a worksheet that has a matching name. First I created a string variable Country that is dynamic and will take the value from each row of the column:

```
For k = 2 To 59
  srange0 = "A" & k & ""
 Country = wsforecast.Range(srange0).value
```

Then I am trying to match this Country with the worksheet name:

```
  If Country = wbregion.Worksheets("Country").Name Then  'subscript out of range 
    For i = 1 To cntyn
      For j = 5 To forec
        If Cells(i, "A").value = rcell Then
           If Cells(i, "C").value = wbregion.Worksheets("Country").Cells(j, "B").value Then
              srange1 = "I" & j & ":" & "n" & j
              srange2 = "D" & i & ":" & "i" & i
              wsforecast.Range(srange2).Value2 = wsregion.Range(srange1).Value2
           End If
        End If
      Next j
     Next i
  End If
Next k
```

But I will receive a message telling me that this method is not supported. Do you have any recommendations on how to make this tab name dynamic? Thank you a lot!

Comment: So, you are then trying to find if `Country` is the name of the worksheet `Country`? Try `If Country = wbregion.Workseets("Country").Name Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get correctly what you need, try changing your loop to this:

```
Dim shCheck as Object
On error Resume next
set shCheck = wbregion.Worksheets(Country)
on error goto 0

If Not (shCheck is nothing) Then   
For i = 1 To cntyn
  For j = 5 To forec
    If Cells(i, "A").value = rcell Then
       If Cells(i, "C").value = wbregion.Worksheets(Country).Cells(j, "B").value Then
          srange1 = "I" & j & ":" & "n" & j
          srange2 = "D" & i & ":" & "i" & i
          wsforecast.Range(srange2).Value2 = wsregion.Range(srange1).Value2
       End If
    End If
  Next j
 Next i
End If
Next k
```

and i also have no idea what is exactly `wbregion` in your code

Edit: might worth explaining a bit - what this does is trying to "grab" the sheet, but you need to make sure it ignores the error if the sheet does not exist, then you are checking if the sheet exists, if it does, the loop will start, if not, it will skip.

Comment: Thanks! But this code will not match Country with the worksheet name?

Comment: @user95902 not sure i understand what you mean? it will try to check if in workbook `wbregion` you got a sheet with the name that has been stored in variable `country`. Btw, i have just fixed a typo i made in my answer - i removed quotes from second appearance of `Country`

Comment: sorry but seems no. in set shCheck = wbregion.Worksheets(Country), shCheck is always "nothing"

Comment: @user95902 ok, when it goes into debug, check if your `country` is in fact correct and is not a blank and also check if you in fact have the worksheet by the name of what you stored in `country` in the workbook which you set to `wbregion`? The check itself should work ok, it is something before that, that is going incorrectly.